# nth day to nth month in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get date between two date range. That is nth day of nth month.
For example, I need to know 23rd day of every 2nd month between January 1, 2015 to December 30, 2015.

I need the query in T-SQL for SQL Server

Comment: Do you have a calendar table available?

Comment: if you're thinking of two different numbers for an example, it's normal to use different letters to represent them (e.g. "nth day of mth month")

Comment: Might you have a period, say, from January 15th 2015 until December 5th 2015? If so, and if you were asked to find the 10th of the month for every 2nd month, what should the first value be? 10th January (ignore the day portion of the start date) or 10th February? Similarly, what should the last value be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use recursive query in MSSQL.

Here the first `WITH DT` is a table where you set up conditions:

```
WITH DT AS
(
  SELECT CAST('January 1, 2015' as datetime) as dStart,
         CAST('December 30, 2015' as datetime) as dFinish,
         31 as nDay,
         2 as nMonth
 ),
 T AS
 (
   SELECT DATEADD(DAY,nDay-1,
                      DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DStart), 0)
                  ) as d,0 as MonthNumber 
   FROM DT
   UNION ALL
   SELECT DATEADD(DAY,nDay-1,
                      DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DStart)
                                     +T.MonthNumber+nMonth,0)
                  )as d, T.MonthNumber+nMonth as MonthNumber
         FROM T,DT
         WHERE DATEADD(DAY,nDay-1,
                      DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DStart)
                                     +T.MonthNumber+nMonth,0)
                  )<=DT.dFinish

 )
 SELECT d FROM T,DT WHERE DAY(d)=DT.nDay
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/3732)</kbd>

Comment: thank, it is creating problem if I take 30 as nDay,  I get the output as:-                                2015-01-30 00:00:00.000
2015-02-28 00:00:00.000
2015-03-28 00:00:00.000
2015-04-28 00:00:00.000
2015-05-28 00:00:00.000
2015-06-28 00:00:00.000
2015-07-28 00:00:00.000
2015-08-28 00:00:00.000
2015-09-28 00:00:00.000
2015-10-28 00:00:00.000
2015-11-28 00:00:00.000
2015-12-28 00:00:00.000

Comment: @AwadeshKr: 28-31 days issue fixed. Please use this new query. It just skips these months (for example FEB 29). If you need these dates just remove the last `WHERE DAY(d)=DT.nDay`

Comment: Thank @valex for your help

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
DECLARE @startDate datetime
DECLARE @endDate datetime
DECLARE @monthToFind INT
DECLARE @dayToFind INT

SET @startDate = '01/01/2015'
SET @endDate = '12/31/2015'
SET @monthToFind = 2
SET @dayToFind = 20

IF MONTH(@startDate) + (@monthToFind - 1) BETWEEN MONTH(@startDate) AND MONTH(@endDate)
AND YEAR(@startDate) = YEAR(@endDate)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @setTheDate datetime
    SET @setTheDate = CAST(MONTH(@startDate) + (@monthToFind - 1) AS varchar) + '/' + CAST(@dayToFind AS varchar) + '/' + CAST(YEAR(@startDate) AS varchar)

    SELECT DATENAME(DW,@setTheDate)
END
```

Comment: Thank, but this is not what I'm trying to get. What I want it to get all date between the range.For example, I need to know 23rd day of every 2nd month between January 1, 2015 to December 30, 2015. My expected output should be
23 january,2015, 23 march, 23 may and so on till december.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly homework, and the point of homework is to learn how things work and to solve problems, not to get others to do it for you. So - pointers for doing this properly, rather than an answer to copy and paste.

- Numbers / tally tables are ideal for this sort of thing. Create a function that returns a list of sequential integers in a range. More general than a calendar table, and you can use it to derive a calendar table later if you need one.
- When you've got that, DATEDIFF will give you the number of days between two dates. Use that to work out the size of your range, DATEADD to increment your date and possibly DATEPART to check that a date is the nth day of the month.

Mess about with those bits for a little while and you'll work it out.